# A pairing of Eilenberg MacLane spaces and the induced map on the homotopy groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given $Sym^{\infty}(P^n)\cong \prod_{k=1}^nK(\mathbb{Z}, 2k)$, we have $\pi_i(Hom(X,Sym^{\infty}(P^n)))= \prod_{k=1}^nH^{2k-i}(X, \mathbb{Z})$. Now since $\mathbb{P}^d = Sym^d(\mathbb{P}^1)$ for all $d$ we have a natural pairing of the form $\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{m+n}$. This induces a pairing of the form $Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^n)\times Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^m)\rightarrow Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m)\rightarrow Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^{m+n})$. This also induces a pairing of the form $Hom(X,Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^n))\times Hom(X,Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^m))\rightarrow Hom(X,Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m))\rightarrow Hom(X,Sym^{\infty}(\mathbb{P}^{m+n}))$. After taking $i$-th homotopy group we get a morphism of the form: $\prod_{k=1}^nH^{2k-i}(X, \mathbb{Z})\times \prod_{k=1}^mH^{2k-i}(X, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \prod_{k=1}^{n+m}H^{2k-i}(X, \mathbb{Z})$. Does this pairing have a name? If $i=0$ is it cup product?